# Got Certificate issue even after installed the Jmeter security certificate

Tags: performance, jmeter, blazemeter

I need to do load testing for Android app using JMeter

- On Mobile Device, Configured Manual Proxy settings and Installed JMeter root certificate
- System and Mobile on Same WiFi only
- On JMeter, Started Recording  Got Report for Mobile open, login and some pages
- On Report, an SSL certificate error is displayed [image]

Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to record your mobile device network traffic using Android >= [7.0 (Nougat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_7.0_Nougat_(API_24)) you need to perform some extra steps in order to configure your application to use JMeter's certificate:

1. In your application [manifest file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) add the following line to the [`<application> tag`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Under [`res` folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) of your application create file `network_security_config.xml` and put the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Build your application in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
4. Replace the application on the device with the newly build debug version - this one you can record with JMeter.

If you don't have access to your application sources you will have to root your device, [convert JMeter's certificate into PEM format using OpenSSL and copy it to Android OS trusted certificates area using ADB](https://blog.jeroenhd.nl/article/android-7-nougat-and-certificate-authorities).

More information: [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Can i proceed these steps for Ionic appication too..?

Comment: The framework doesn't really matter, it's Android OS enhanced network security. If your application can be run on Android < = 6 you can use the appropriate device or emulator for recording without having to rebuild the application